# wcf slow connection and number of connections in the pool

Tags: wcf, client, connection-pooling

I have a wcf client.
The client calls a function and then closes.

If I use netstat there is only one connection.

I made an experiment.
In the server function I put Thread.sleep(10000).

Then again I started the client.

With netstat I found out that there are 5 connections.

Why when the response is slow the client opens more connections than one ?

Regards

Comment: What binding do you use? Did you make first measurement after starting new client or did the client already run?

Answer (score 0):

Nettcp connection are pooled and if you had your process running for a while then you see that these would be reused and a new one would be created if an existing one is being used and returned to the pool. So your usage will determine how the pool functions.

https://web.archive.org/web/20221126150141/https://kennyw.com/?p=173